# Unable to run java file in GITHUB using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, github

I am new to Jenkins and GITHUB.I have configured Jenkins with GITHUB and I don't see any issues with configuration.

I am running the file using windows batch
My commands are -

javac HelloJenkins.java

java HelloJenkins

Can someone tell me where am I going wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFilM.png)

Comment: Jenkins can't find the HelloJenkins.java file, where do you think Jenkins will get the HelloJenkins.java file from?

Comment: from the GITHUB path i have mentioned. As per logs i am seeing it is able to goto the location. Am i missing anything?

Comment: Please don't post a picture of text when the text itself suffices. Also, if you are looking for a a files called `.java`, you should name  it such...
https://github.com/ganesh-n-ayyer/test1Repo/blob/main/HelloJenkins